# ImportError: cannot import name RequestSite

Tags: python, django

When trying to run python manage.py runserver

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x103828e60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
ImportError: cannot import name RequestSite
```

I am running Django 1.10 and Python 2.7.

Comment: WHich django apps are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[`RequestSite`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/#requestsite-objects) does not reside in sites.models.

As per the [1.8 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/#requestsite-objects) It has been deprecated since 1.7

> Deprecated since version 1.7:
>
> This class used to be defined in django.contrib.sites.models. The old import location will work until Django 1.9.

it can be found at

```
django.contrib.sites.requests.RequestSite
```

---

Assuming you're using the popular `django-registration-redux`, their most recent version has a [fix for this](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/admin.py#L3), so if this is the case you should update the version of that.

Comment: It looks like his django-registration package has not been updated for Django 1.10, maybe he has a fixed pip requirements file and just updated Django to Django 1.10

Comment: @lapinkoira - Good point, I didn't notice what was importing it.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my requirements.txt file and that sorted the issue.